# Django & SQLite: DurationField arithmetics

Tags: python, django, sqlite, duration, timedelta

I have the following model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    start = models.TimeField()
    finish = models.TimeField()
    penalty = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)  # penalty in minutes
```

And the following queryset annotation in admin

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(
        total_time=ExpressionWrapper(
            F("finish") - F("start") + F("penalty") * 60,
            output_field=DurationField()
        )
    )
    return qs
```

When I inspect the annotation value for a row where `penalty != 0` I get something like `datetime.timedelta(0, 1800, 1800)` (in this case penalty is 30 minutes).

However, I expect a timedelta like `datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)`. Can someone explain, please?

I've also tried

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(
        duration=ExpressionWrapper(
            F("finish") - F("start"),
            output_field=DurationField()
        )
    )
    qs = qs.annotate(
        total_time=ExpressionWrapper(
            F("duration") + F("route_shortening_penalty") * 60,
            output_field=DurationField()
        )
    )
    return qs
```

and even

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.annotate(
        duration=ExpressionWrapper(
            F("finish") - F("start"),
            output_field=DurationField()
        ),
        penalty_duration=ExpressionWrapper(
            F("penalty") * 60,
            output_field=DurationField()
        )
    )
    qs = qs.annotate(
        total_time=ExpressionWrapper(
            F("duration") + F("penalty_duration"),
            output_field=DurationField()
        )
    )
    return qs
```

both of which lead to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 604, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 223, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1793, in changelist_view
    'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 63, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1009, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "/home/dm/.virtualenvs/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/operations.py", line 573, in convert_durationfield_value
    return datetime.timedelta(0, 0, value)
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta microseconds component: str
```

I am using `Python 3.6.7`, `Django==2.1.7` and `SQLite version 3022000`.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense if penalty were a `DurationField` instead of an `IntegerField`?

Comment: @JohnGordon tried that too, see updated question.

Comment: Why don't you use class properties instead of annotation?

Comment: @Pedro because it's not possible to sort changelist_view on properties. I want to sort based on the annotation result.

Comment: I don't see any code that says you tried a different model definition.  I only see changes to `get_queryset()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get `datetime.timedelta(0, 1800, 1800)` instead of the correct `datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)` then you're obviously almost there.

I would assume that the 1800 seconds are the difference between `F("finish")` and `F("start")`, while the 1800 microseconds come from `F("penalty") * 60`.

Multiply with `60*1000*1000` instead of `60` to convert `penalty` from minutes to microseconds:

```
total_time=ExpressionWrapper(
    F("finish") - F("start") + F("penalty") * 60000000,
    output_field=DurationField()
)
```

Comment: OK, so what worked was to multiply by `60000000` (1 second = 1000000 microsecond). Accepted as you pointed me in the right direction, please update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I should have run the conversion by my kids first.